# Latching push button with electronic reset

Tags: button, reset, latch

I'm looking for a latching push button switch that can be reset electronically.

After much searching I managed to find this post: [Resettable mechanical switch?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91842/resettable-mechanical-switch)

which links to this switch:
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/A8GS-S1305/SW1533-ND/4248837

which is really close, but I'd really prefer a push button instead of a toggle switch. Bonus points if the push button has different physical states (like the on state is pushed in further or lit up or both) and the physical state gets reset when the switch is electronically reset (button pops out, light goes off).

Has anyone ever run across this particular type of button? I know I can put together a circuit to achieve what I want pretty easily using a momentary button but it would save me some headache if there was a nice contained package that does what I want. The one I linked is so close!

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic in this forum.  Reference: Help->Tour->Don't ask about...Shopping or buying recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the unit price of the switch that you found it becomes pretty obvious for most projects that another approach is more appropriate. A momentary tact switch can be made to operate in a push push toggle mode. Some low cost tact switches even have integrated LEDs to light the knob or button. If the lowest cost approach is used an SMT LED is located just adjacent to the tact switch on the board.

It is possible to design circuitry that implements the current state holding for the toggle status however these days when virtually every gadget has a microprocessor embedded into it it makes a lot of sense for the MCU to monitor the tact switch presses, de-bounce them and the track the toggle state in a memory location. The MCU can then also control the state LED via another output pin. A huge advantage of this approach is that the toggle state can be kept in a serial EEPROM byte so that when there is a power loss / restore the toggle state can be set back to what it was last set to.