# Mechanical Switch with electronic trigger/gate

Tags: switches, relay, mechanical

There are any part in market that consists in a mechanical Switch which can be turn ON or OFF by a person, and by a electronic? Something like a real switch with a tiny servo inside to push on or off?
My main porpouse is to avoid relay that consume some current and mosfet as well.
Need to deal good amount of current in AC

Comment: How much current? I have used 1kA contactor switches with solenoid assist or manual lever

Comment: 220V 16A Max, need a switch with that inbuilt if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If the only problem with a relay is that you want to avoid the stand-by current while activated, there are variations called a [latching relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay#Latching_relay).

They keep their state even when they are unpowered, and they are available in different configurations.

---

<sup>This was originally a comment, but apparently it was helpful.</sup>

Comment: Still need a push button that user can interact with, and if relay change state that button change position too, is that possible?

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91842/resettable-mechanical-switch?rq=1 which talks about a rocker switch that can be turned off with an electrical signal.